# How would I go about setting up this modal to toggle?

Tags: reactjs, redux, toggle, mern

I'm trying to get an editModal and a detailsModal to open on click. I set up actions and reducers for the modal so it can be stored in the global state and it works, but currently the modals are set to open automatically and I cannot close them. I believe it's something wrong with my logic, but it seems like it would be rather straightforward. Does anyone have any tips on how to complete this?

**modalReducer.js**

```
import { OPEN_MODAL } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  modal: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**ClientEditModal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editClient } from "../actions/clientActions";
import { openModal } from "../actions/modalActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ClientEditModal extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.editClient();
    this.props.openModal();
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.props.modal,
    });
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Close modal
    this.toggle();
  };

  displayClient = (clients, _id) => {
    return (
      <FormGroup key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
        <Label for="name"> Name </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id="client"
          value={clients.name}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Label for="email"> Email </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id="client"
          value={clients.email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Label for="number"> Number </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="number"
          id="number"
          value={clients.number}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
          Submit Client Edit
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    return (
      // Split button into separate component
      <div>
        <Button
          color="dark"
          style={{ marginBottom: "2rem", marginLeft: "1rem" }}
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >
          Edit
        </Button>

        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.modal}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          style={{ padding: "50px" }}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}> Edit</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              {clients.map(this.displayClient)}
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ClientEditModal.propTypes = {
  editClient: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
  modal: state.modal,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { editClient, openModal })(
  ClientEditModal
);
```

**modalActions.js**

```
import { OPEN_MODAL } from "./types";

export const openModal = () => {
  return {
    type: OPEN_MODAL,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is - your `toggle` function, `!this.props.modal` will invert the value of modal and the component always holds the value of true.

So, one option is to maintain another action for closing modal.

See the updated code snippets below.

**Reducer**

```js
import { OPEN_MODAL } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  modal: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: false,
      };
    case CLOSE_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Actions**

```js
import { OPEN_MODAL } from "./types";

export const openModal = () => {
  return {
    type: OPEN_MODAL,
  };
};
export const closeModal = () => {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_MODAL,
  };
};
```

**ClientModal.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editClient } from "../actions/clientActions";
import { openModal } from "../actions/modalActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ClientEditModal extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.editClient();
    this.props.openModal();
  }

  toggle = () => {
    // this.setState({ //<---- setstate is not required as once the state in the store is updated, then the component is re-rendered automatically
    //   modal: !this.props.modal, //<---- once toggle is executed - it is always true
    //});
   this.props.closeModal()
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Close modal
    this.toggle();
  };

  displayClient = (clients, _id) => {
    return (
      <FormGroup key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
        <Label for="name"> Name </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id="client"
          value={clients.name}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Label for="email"> Email </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id="client"
          value={clients.email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Label for="number"> Number </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="number"
          id="number"
          value={clients.number}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
          Submit Client Edit
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    return (
      // Split button into separate component
      <div>
        <Button
          color="dark"
          style={{ marginBottom: "2rem", marginLeft: "1rem" }}
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >
          Edit
        </Button>

        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.modal}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          style={{ padding: "50px" }}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}> Edit</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              {clients.map(this.displayClient)}
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ClientEditModal.propTypes = {
  editClient: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
  modal: state.modal,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { editClient, openModal, closeModal })(
  ClientEditModal
);
```

Comment: toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
    //   modal: !this.props.modal, //<---- once toggle is executed - it is always true
      this.props.closeModal()
    });
  };                              this part doesn't seem to register

Comment: hi - forgot to comment `setState` line of code... i have updated the code snippet in the answer....basically you don't need `setstate` there...because once the state in the store is updated, then the component is re-rendered automatically ...

Comment: Hm I did that, but it doesn't seem to be working. Should I maybe set up a conditional for the toggle? I still don't know why it's not working. The modal state is set to false initially. It shouldn't even be open now.

Comment: i see - what is the error ... have you imported the closeModal ? ... also is it possible to put your code in codesandbox?

Comment: I have imported the action. I'm helping my fiance build a desk right now, but I can put it on codesandbox soon. I'm not receiving any error. The toggle just isn't working and the modals are by default open.

Comment: Actually I don't know if I can. It uses the MongoDB database so I'd have to rework some of the code I suppose.

Comment: you can just put your react related code only (dosen't have to be working) ... i believe it should some simple fix ..it helps me see all code easily

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-noyce-641wz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: see here https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-modal-issue-fix-mjkjm .... your code is updated and ClientDetails modal and edit client modal(inside table) is working properly ... i have used local state in clientDetails modal and reducer in edit client modal...go thru the code and make the other modals (such as details modal inside table) working  ... use separate state in the reducer for handling opening and closing of details modal etc..

Comment: Well, I need to have the modal state in the redux store. Eventually, I need the toggle functionality to be used in the "edit" and "details" buttons inside of the ClientTable.